# OSX + PhpStorm: Disable non-breaking spaces

Tags: macos, phpstorm

How can I remove the non-breaking spaces that appear when I click **Shift + Alt + Space**? They are really annoying when writing code since they produce errors.

I have tried adding the following to *DefaultKeyBinding.dict*:

```
{
  "~ " = ("insertText:", " ");
}
```

I would like it to work in both Coda + PhpStorm. Thanks!

Comment: Partially related: you may install "Zero Width Character Locator" plugin in PhpStorm -- at very least it will be highlighting such symbols with "Error" severity so it's easier to spot and fix them.

Comment: That is not quite what I'm looking for. Although, it's better than nothing :)